# Dart: How to determine the movement of a block?

Tags: html, css, web, drag-and-drop, dart

I need to understand which block is moving and rushing to another block. How do I know if the block .one(or .two) drop to block .three?

dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

main() {
 var one = document.querySelector('.one');
 one.onDragStart.listen(_onDragStart);
 one.onDragEnter.listen(_onDragStop);

 var two = document.querySelector('.two');
 one.onDragStart.listen(_onDragStart);
 one.onDragEnter.listen(_onDragStop);
}
_onDragStop(MouseEvent event) {
    print('stop');
}
_onDragStart(MouseEvent event) {
    print('start');
 }
```

html

```
<div class="one" draggable="true"></div>
<div class="two" draggable="true"></div>
<br><br><br>
<div class="three"></div>
```

css

```
.one{
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.two{
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.three{
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

I just started to learn this language. I ask the help of the community.

Comment: That's not really related to Dart, rather than to how the browser works. There is not much difference between JS and Dart in how the browser API is used.

Comment: What @GünterZöchbauer said. Better to look for an answer in the Javascript world. It will be pretty easy to map things back to Dart!